# Hide objects behind invisible objects in unreal engine with Hololens 2

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens

i need to hide objects behind other invisible objects in Hololens 2.

Indeed, I must display virtual cars that can move behind a building.
The buildings are mehes (FBX) superimposed on reality, but which are not displayed. They only serve as a mask.
(I can’t use spatial mapping because the buildings must be those coming from an FBX).

I do not find tutorials or documentation for that. Is there specific function in Hololens to do that ?

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to occlude your holograms based on other holograms? If so, any 3D Game Engine can do that.

Comment: Yes, i want to occlude my holograms by other holograms, but some holograms must be invisible (but occluder)

Comment: How can i do that in unreal ?